# Genetic algorithm with plateauing searchspace

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, genetic-algorithm, cells, tabular

I came across this interesting problem of optimizing tabular data.

We extracted some tabular data from a pdf, but it's not perfect.
A simplified example looks something like this:

```
FileNumber: 121.345 ; The first institute  ; tel. 34567890    ; capacity: 5
FileNumber: 122.365 ; The great            ; second institute ; tel. 34567890       ; capacity: 7
FileNumber: 234.345 ; The third            ; tel. 34567890    ; capacity: 4
FileNumber: 121.565 ; Some crazy institute ; that has         ; a really long name  ; tel. 34567890 ; capacity: 9
FileNumber: 156.347 ; the fifth institute  ; tel. 34567890    ; capacity: 45
FileNumber: 123.335 ; the sixth            ; tel. 34567890    ; capacity: 2
FileNumber: 117.385 ; the seventh          ; tel. 34567890    ; capacity: 6
```

This data is a near perfect table except some cells had a new line in their content causing them to span 2 cells, while push the cells to the right further to the right.

The ideal outcome would be:

```
FileNumber: 121.345 ; The first institute                               ; tel. 34567890 ; capacity: 5
FileNumber: 122.365 ; The great second institute                        ; tel. 34567890 ; capacity: 7
FileNumber: 234.345 ; The third                                         ; tel. 34567890 ; capacity: 4
FileNumber: 121.565 ; Some crazy institute that has a really long name  ; tel. 34567890 ; capacity: 9
FileNumber: 156.347 ; the fifth institute                               ; tel. 34567890 ; capacity: 45
FileNumber: 123.335 ; the sixth                                         ; tel. 34567890 ; capacity: 2
FileNumber: 117.385 ; the seventh                                       ; tel. 34567890 ; capacity: 6
```

Where it combines certain cells so all rows have the identical number of cells (equal to the number of cells of the row that has the least number of cells to begin with)

This problem seems like a good candidate to solve using an evolutionary algorithm, wouldn't you say?

- Huge search space
- Good solutions can be enhanced upon
- Great solutions are easily identifiable

---

Search space

The algorithm should identify which cells to merge. Each row knows how many cells it needs to merge to make its length match the shortest row length.

So the search space is a 2D array of rows, where each row defines cell divisions that should be left alone (keep 2 cells separate), or be taken out (merge 2 cells).

---

Fitness function

I calculate the fitness by counting the characters that are used in each column. And dividing the characters into 3 classes: lowercase a-z, uppercase A-Z, numerals 0-9, each special character in a separate class.

Now the score is calculated per column:
* High frequencies for a certain character are encouraged
* Use of many character classes is discouraged
* Use of many characters is discouraged

---

I implemented this algorithm, but it seems to get stuck in local optima. I think the searchspace doesn't really resemble a hill surface, where you can follow the slope:

[image: smooth surface with peaks and valleys]

But a more discreet surface like this:

[image: discrete flat surfaces at various altitudes]

Full implementation:

https://github.com/bertyhell/PdfToCsv/blob/genetic-column-optimizer/PdfToCsv/GeneticRowOptimizer.cs#L27

---

Any advice on how to get the algorithm to behave better? Or other approaches I can try?

Comment: do all rows have `'tel. '` substring?

Comment: yes, but i'm trying to come up with a solution that doesn't rely on specific substrings. So it can be used on an arbitrary pdf file. See: https://github.com/bertyhell/PdfToCsv#pdftocsv